# Is a deserialised object the same instance as the original

Tags: java, serialization

When I instantiate an object from a class, an object is saved in the java heap. When I save the object by serializing it and I later deserialize the object, do I understand correctly that the object will now have a new heap address but will still be the EXACT SAME instance of the class.

Comment: originalObj == deserilized will be false however originalObj.equals(deserilized) should be true.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the answere is no, the two references will not be pointing to the same Object A

Comment: If you want to expand your question, don't do it in the comments, do it in the body of the question. The comments are not a place for long discussions or code or anything formatted.

Comment: Write some code and test it, using `==` and `equals` to answer the question on your own.  If you don't understand the results, post the code here for discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does serialization preserve object identity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351706/does-serialization-preserve-object-identity)

Comment: @robbmj this depends on the implementation of the equals method. For many classes it works, for the default implementation it doesn't.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, interesting I tested for a collection of strings, now that I think about it, that is not a good test as of course the `equals` method is overridden in the `String` class and in whatever class `Arrays.asList` returns. Thanks for the insight, I will conduct another test.

Comment: 'The object will now have a new heap address but will still be the EXACT SAME instance of the class' is already a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer to your question cannot be just a yes or no. To analyze the concept is required. I will suggest you to take a pencil and paper and do it yourself keeping the below points in mind.

- All java objects are created in java heap (except for some which are
  kept in pool but for you question we will skip them for now).
- When an instance of a class is created using new keyword,
  deserialization, clone method or reflection api's newInstance method,
  a new space in heap is reserved and we assign it to a object reference
  (the reference can be of the object's class or one of the super
  classes of the object's class - again we can ignore this detail for
  now).
- When you save your object, the object's state is saved with all it's
  nested objects.
- When you deserialize your object, the object will create a new entry
  in heap which will not have any references to any of the objects.

Look at the below diagram for picturizing the above concept in you context:

[image]

All the object A references are pointing to one heap entry and if you try objectB.getObjectA() == objectC.getObjectA() or any other such operation, you will get true.

**Case 1** When you save the objects separately and deserialize them here is what happens in the heap:

[image]

As you can figure out now that objectBcopy.getObjectA() == objectCcopy.getObjectA() will not return true as the references of object A for the copied objects are no more same.

**Case 2** On the contrary, when you save the objects in a single file and deserialize them later, here is what happens in the heap:

[image]

As you can figure out now that objectBcopy.getObjectA() == objectCcopy.getObjectA() will now be true as the references of object A copy are same, but that's still a new copy of object A.

A quick program to support my deductions (Case 1 and Case 2):

```
public class Test{

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        A a = new A();

        B b = new B();
        b.a = a;

        C c = new C();
        c.a = a;

        System.out.println("b.a == c.a is " + (b.a == c.a));

        // Case 1 - when two diferent files are used to write the objects
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\b.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(b);
        oos.close();
        fout.close();

        fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\c.ser");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(c);
        oos.close();
        fout.close();

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:\\b.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        B bCopy = (B) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();

        fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:\\c.ser");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        C cCopy = (C) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println("Case 1 - bCopy.a == cCopy.a is " + (bCopy.a == cCopy.a));

        // Case 2 - when both the objects are saved in the same file
        fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\both.ser");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(b);
        oos.writeObject(c);
        oos.close();
        fout.close();


        fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:\\both.ser");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        bCopy = (B) in.readObject();
        cCopy = (C) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println("Case 2 - bCopy.a == cCopy.a is " + (bCopy.a == cCopy.a));
    }
}

class A implements Serializable{

}

class B implements Serializable{
    A a;
}

class C implements Serializable{
    A a;
}
```

With the following output:

```
 b.a == c.a is true
 Case 1 - bCopy.a == cCopy.a is false
 Case 2 - bCopy.a == cCopy.a is true
```

Comment: "... but that's still a new copy of object A." So if I change a field of Object A Copy (ex. Age), the change in object A copy will not be reflected in the Object A(s) inside BCDE?

Comment: that's correct.  As the object is in a different heap address. if the answer helped you,  please accept the same.

Comment: In that case, may you suggest a way so I can accomplish what I want to achieve as illustrated in the example above?

Comment: For that, you will have to replace your reference of object A within B, C, D and E with the one already present. For this, you can replace the reference of Object A after deserialization by implementing your own readObject method.

Answer (score 3):

Before serializing:

```
A originalA = ...;
B.a == C.a == D.a == E.a == originalA
```

All `B.a`, `C.a`, `D.a` and `E.a` point to the same reference of `A`, `originalA`.

After serializing and deserializing:

```
A otherA = ...;
B.a == C.a == D.a == E.a == otherA
```

All `B.a`, `C.a`, `D.a` and `E.a` point to the same reference of `A`, `otherA`.

However:

```
originalA != otherA
```

though

```
originalA.equals(otherA) == true
```

*Note:* `equals()` will return `true` only if it is **overriden** to *consistently* check equality based on serialized fields. Otherwise, it *might* return `false`.

---

**EDIT:**

Proof:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Sample {

    static class A implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    static class B implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        A a;
    }

    static class C implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        A a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        A originalA = new A();

        B b = new B();
        b.a = originalA;

        C c = new C();
        c.a = originalA;

        System.out.println("b.a == c.a is " + (b.a == c.a));

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(b);
        oos.writeObject(c);
        oos.close();
        fout.close();

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        B bDeserialized = (B) in.readObject();
        C cDeserialized = (C) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();

        System.out.println("bDeserialized.a == cDeserialized.a is " + (bDeserialized.a == cDeserialized.a));
    }
}
```

Comment: While the equals contract should always observed when overriding it, it is not what is necessary to return true (after all, the original Object.equals also observes this contract). What is important is that equals compares those fields which are serialized/unserialized by the serialization mechanism, in a compatible way.

Answer (score 2):

The deserialized instance will definitely be a distinct instance from the original, as in `deserialized != original` will always be true.

The deserialized instance may or may not be equal to the original instance, as in `deserialized.equals(original)`. For a reasonable implementation of a `Serializable` class, `equals` probably will be true after deserialization, but it is trivial to create a class for which this does not hold:

```
class Pathological implements Serializable {
  transient int value;

  Pathological(int value) { this.value = value; }

  @Override public int hashCode() { return value; }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) { return true; }
    if (other instanceof Pathological) {
      return ((Pathological) other).value == this.value;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Unless you happen to pass zero when constructing the `Pathological`, the instances won't be equal after serialization/deserialization, since the value of `value` won't be serialized (as it is transient).

Answer (score 1):

No,Simple answer is that deserialized object will not be the same instance in memory ! It will allocate new memory for same.Also go through http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html link which contains example of retrieving object using deserialization with singleton !Also go through readResolve() method in depth, it will be helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

No they will not be the same object in memory `originalObj == deserilized` will be false, however `originalObj.equals(deserilized)` should be true.

> Objects B, C, D and E. All of them when instantiated, had Object A. Then, let's assume I serialize and deserialized all of them. When I change a field of Object A after deserialization, is there a way to reflect such change in the Object A(s) in BCDE?

If I understand you correctly the answer is no, the references will not be pointing to the same Object A

However if you so desire you can explicitly set all of the references of Object A in each object B, C, D and E to point to the same instance of Object A

Here is a demo to illustrate the points made.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {  
  public static void main(String... aArguments) {  
    List<Quark> quarks = Arrays.asList(
      new Quark("up"), new Quark("down")
    );

    serialize(quarks);
    List<Quark> recoveredQuarks = deserialize();

    System.out.println(quarks == recoveredQuarks);               // false
    System.out.println(quarks.equals(recoveredQuarks));          // true

    System.out.println(quarks.get(0) == recoveredQuarks.get(0)); // false

    // but you can set it to the same instance
    recoveredQuarks.set(0, quarks.get(0));
    System.out.println(quarks.get(0) == recoveredQuarks.get(0)); // true

    quarks.get(0).name = "Charm";
    boolean b = quarks.get(0).name == recoveredQuarks.get(0).name;
    System.out.println(b);                                       // true
  }

  static void serialize(List<Quark> quarks) {
    try {
      OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("quarks.ser");
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
      ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
      output.writeObject(quarks);
      output.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  static List<Quark> deserialize() {
    List<Quark> recoveredQuarks = null;
    try {
      InputStream file = new FileInputStream("quarks.ser");
      InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
      ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
      recoveredQuarks = (List<Quark>)input.readObject();
      input.close();
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){ }
    catch(IOException ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
    return recoveredQuarks;
  }
}

class Quark implements Serializable {
    String name;
    Quark(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o != null && o instanceof Quark) {
        return this.name.equals(((Quark)o).name);
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```