# how does java deep copy utility reserve objects' inner relationships?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I was using apache `SerializationUtils` to deep copy objects and found something amazing. For example, Object `A` has 2 member `B1`,`B2`, and both of them has the same member `C` (**refering to same object**).
After deep copy, `A'` was created , and I was expecting `B1'` has member `C1'`, `B2'` has member `C2'`. But it occurs that both `B1'` and `B2'` has the same member `C'`.

It seems that after deep copy, the object hierarchy and relationship is maintained. How is that implemented?

Comment: Note that ObjectOutputStream already does this by itself. So if they are using that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1351706/14955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider two references as having 'the same identity' if they are pointing to the same object. That is, given:

```
Object a = ...;
Object b = ...;
```

Then `a` and `b` are 'identical' if this holds: `a == b`, which will only hold if they point at the same object.

Note that `a.equals(b)` is different; any two references for which that holds can be considered 'equal', but 2 objects may be involved. Trivial example:

```
String a = new String("Hello");
String b = new String("Hello");
a == b; // this is false
a.equals(b); // this is true
```

It is possible to figure out if 2 references are *identical* and not just *equal*.

One easy check is literally what I just showed you: `==`, which checks *identical* and not *equal*.

Most likely, the code in SerializationUnits uses [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) which is a map that maps on identity (more or less, 'the pointer'). WHM is mostly an internal implementation, but note that you can always get the identity hashcode via `System.identityHashCode` which returns the same value for the same object, even if that object is mutated. In theory, `a.hashCode()` can return a different value (and for mutable objects, it tends to), but `System.identityHashCode(a)` is the same value for any given instance for the lifetime of a VM.

Plain jane `HashMap` uses `a.hashCode()` to know which bucket to look at, and then `a.equals(b)` to scan for equality.

A `WeakHashMap` uses `System.identityHashCode(a)` to know which bucket to look at, and then `a == b` to scan for equality.

Armed with that, writing a serializer that preserves hierarchy and relationship is then trivial.

Note also that without such a mechanism, solid serialization is **impossible**. After all, imagine this structure:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(list); // ooooh, recursion!
```

without tools like `WeakHashMap`, any attempt to serialize this construct will result in a `StackOverflowError`, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Apache library, but most probably it keeps a map of instances copied so far. And if it encounters an instance `C` to be copied, it first checks whether there already exists a copy `C'` of that instance. If so, it uses the existing copy. If not, it creates a deep copy of `C`, giving `C'` and stores that copy in the map.

One fine point to consider: I guess that Apache bases the existence test on the on the `==` operator and not the `equals()` method, as the `==` operator will give the cleanest result, best resembling the original references structure. If not, two distinct instances `C1` and `C2` that just happen to satisfy the `equals()` test would end up as a single copy `C'`.